# Break-pointing Sagas, Redux and Co. with VS and Chrome

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, redux-saga

**The setting:** I am using Visual Studio (Professional 2017), the latest Chrome with the [React Developer Tools plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi). I am trying to debug somebody else's ReactJs project. I am not new to React, but I am still not very comfortable with hierarchical Sagas, Reducers, and Event-Handlers. With hierarchy I mean that that there are e.g. multiple `sagas.ts` in different folder levels, and the same is true for `reducers.ts`, `actions.ts`, `selector.ts`. My general challenge is how to structurally approach such a setup.

**What I tried:** I tried break-pointing respective component `myView` using Chrome's *Developer Tools* > *Sources* and then on the left side on the tab *Page* the path `webpack://` > `./src/myView/components/myFaultyThingy.tsx`, but I learned that I cannot set breakpoints e.g. in the `render()` function. Other functions inside the `myView/sagas.ts` are never called, although they are supposedly triggered.

**How can I follow the values of variables inside functions where I cannot set breakpoints?**

Comment: Do you use regenerator to transform your sagas during build?  Do you use sourcemaps? I found it helpful to avoid sorucemaps in general since they seem to be more often broken than not and just use the `retainLines` babel option. I would also disable regenerator for dev enviroment. After that I think you should be able to use the breakpoints. Otherwise, there is always the option to console.log everything :D

Comment: May be you are placing breakpoints in functions that never get called. you can validate by placing bunch of console.log statements in the code. You can download Redux dev tools and see what all actions gets fired and step through them, that will probably help you whats going on in the app when you do something. You can backtrace on those fired actions and navigate to the code that fires that particular action or listens for that particular action in saga watchers.